# Will all iOS 6 installed devices has camera?

Tags: ios, iphone

May i know whether all `iOS 6` installed devices `(iPad, iPhone and iPod)` should have camera?

Thanks!

Comment: may i know why using google is so hard? http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5457?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US ?

Comment: @Volker I'm not asking about the iOS 6 features. i'm just asking about that if a device has been installed iOS 6, should it has camera?

Comment: @Volker Actually all of the devices with iOS 6 have a camera (but may lack some camera features) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices . @Natarajan you may still check if a device has camera at runtime: `[UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]`

Comment: If you have an app that requires a camera (ie it won't work without one) you can declare the camera as a requirement - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app requires the presence of a camera (ie it won't work or has no useful functions without a camera) then you can specify the camera as a [required device capability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3)

This will prevent the app from installing on devices that do not have a camera

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

NSArray *videoHardwareDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

if ( [videoHardwareDevices count] > 0 ){


    NSLog(@"YES I have camera");

}
else{

    NSLog(@"NO camera");
}
```

Comment: +1 for you, But We can check using [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] ( without importing AVFoundation framework)

Comment: Yes you can, through UIKit